# How can I apt-get from the Maverick repository into Lucid?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, package-management

There is a newer version of `xdotool` in the Maverick repository. There are new features available which I need in the Maverick version.

Is there a simple way to install the Maverick version? By *simple*, I don't want to have to learn the intricacies of installing from source today, but am willing to understand the individual steps if available. I haven't quite figured out the whole `.configure` thing yet.

So is there maybe a simple, one-off, way to get it via synaptic Package Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can download from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/xdotool), check if you don't have dependency problem

if you want to search for a specific package you can do it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Thanks... nice one..  (there was one dependency.. your second link was helpful)